# Hyperlink/css issue

Tags: html, css

I have the weirdest reaction on my page. My hyperlinks act as plain text. Not as a link. I just can't click on the links. Here is the thing, if I hide some of of the divs in the page the links are now working.

Here is what I get from reading the source of my page.

**HTML**

```
<div id="prodMenu">
  <div id="Menu"><a href="product.php">All</a></div>
  <div id="Menu"><a href="product.php?cat=Snake Whips">Snake Whips</a></div>
  <div id="Menu"><a href="product.php?cat=Floggers">Floggers</a></div>
  <div id="Menu"><a href="product.php?cat=Hand Floggers">Hand Floggers</a></div>
</div>
```

Here is the css related to my menu section

**CSS**

```
#prodMenu{
    position:absolute;
    width: 1000px;
    left: 50%;
    top:0px;
    margin-left: -500px;
}
#prodMenu > #Menu{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font:10px;
}
#prodMenu > #Menu a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#838F97;
}
#prodMenu > #Menu a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#C0E73D;
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Don't use same id names for multiple elements (#Menu)

Comment: Yeah.  Use a class instead <div class="Menu">  And then change your CSS selectors from #Menu to .Menu

Comment: Noted, I will change the ID's to classes. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I hide some of the divs in the page the links are now working

You have a [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) problem try setting this:

```
#prodMEnu {
   z-index:1000
}
```

---

As noted on the comments don't use the same **ID** on multiple elements, **ID** must be unique. Use classnames instead.

Comment: You are the best my friend. Thanks that was my issue.